# I am new to running more complex commands on the command line and need help figuring out what is going wrong here

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, scripting

I want to run a one-liner to enable me to get the hash of a string and eventually compare it to a hash I can just copy at the end of the command later. I'm confident I can figure out how to do the comparison once I figure out what is wrong with my output. The goal for now is to just print the hash of a file via one line with certutil since it's native to Windows. I perform this:

```
setlocal & set "firstLine=1" & for /f "skip=1delims=" %i in ('certutil -hashfile apache-ant-1.10.6-bin.zip SHA512') do ( if %firstLine% EQU 1 (set "x=%i" & set "firstLine=0" & echo %x%)) & endlocal
```

and end up with:

```
C:\Users\John\Downloads>(if %firstLine% EQU 1 (set "x=9ba9467f05f1c7fa7161f857b0085461ce28401a2fe01a8062eec2254eaafc4b239fb3dc9298b5df5f27c2bb64618a8606a6885aa171604c541f4d5fe394b361"   & set "firstLine=0"   & echo %x% ) )  & endlocal

C:\Users\John\Downloads>(if %firstLine% EQU 1 (set "x=CertUtil: -hashfile command completed successfully."   & set "firstLine=0"   & echo %x% ) )  & endlocal
```

and then next time executing, I get:

```
C:\Users\John\Downloads>(if 1 EQU 1 (set "x=9ba9467f05f1c7fa7161f857b0085461ce28401a2fe01a8062eec2254eaafc4b239fb3dc9298b5df5f27c2bb64618a8606a6885aa171604c541f4d5fe394b361"   & set "firstLine=0"   & echo %x% ) )  & endlocal
%x%

C:\Users\John\Downloads>(if 1 EQU 1 (set "x=CertUtil: -hashfile command completed successfully."   & set "firstLine=0"   & echo %x% ) )  & endlocal
%x%
```

and then (repeating with a pattern of firstLine being 1 then 0 after this execution):

```
C:\Users\John\Downloads>(if 0 EQU 1 (set "x=9ba9467f05f1c7fa7161f857b0085461ce28401a2fe01a8062eec2254eaafc4b239fb3dc9298b5df5f27c2bb64618a8606a6885aa171604c541f4d5fe394b361"   & set "firstLine=0"   & echo CertUtil: -hashfile command completed successfully. ) )  & endlocal

C:\Users\John\Downloads>(if 0 EQU 1 (set "x=CertUtil: -hashfile command completed successfully."   & set "firstLine=0"   & echo CertUtil: -hashfile command completed successfully. ) )  & endlocal
```

It seems like everything after do is being executed again as a string. The first line of output is skipped, but since everything within the if statement can't execute, the next two lines of the for statement are "executed".

Edit: Got rid of delayed expansion since it wasn't being used.

Comment: why are you forced to do this on one line?

Comment: @Hogan I'm not, but that would be much easier than entering multiple lines.

Comment: no, it would not be easier since batch cares about line feeds in some cases.  Re-write it with line feeds like you see in all the examples

Comment: I mean when I want to enter it whenever I verify files, i don't want to type all the lines every time. Are you saying it's not possible to do with a one-liner?

Comment: you shouldn't enter it every time you should make a batch file.  use `%1` for command line parameters.  I won't speak to if it is possible or not since I'm not clear on your requirements.  But I do know some things won't work on a single line in MS batch.  This is also true of born shell and C shell.  These 30+ year old scripting languages are not as elegant as modern stuff.

Comment: You've enabled delayed expansion but not used it, and even if you had the variables you'd set under `SetLocal`, you `EndLocal`ed too!

Comment: I suggest to use powershell as a tool for this `powershell -NoP -C "(Get-FileHash -Alg sha512 file.zip).Hash"`

Comment: Don't set `firstLine` to `0` or `1`, just set it to something to represent True and clear it to represent False, then you can do `if defined`, which does not require delayed expansion; for variable `x` you will need that though if you want to keep everything in a single line...

Comment: @LotPings Thanks a lot, I got it working with your help! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easier to also do the input/comparison in PowerShell

```
powershell -NoP -C "if ((Read-Host 'Enter sha512') -eq (Get-FileHash -Alg sha512 file.zip).Hash){'Match'}else{'no Match'}"
```

Or do it completely in PowerShell

```
if ((Read-Host 'Enter sha512') -eq (Get-FileHash -Alg sha512 file.zip).Hash){'Match'}else{'no Match'}
```

Comment: This is much cleaner than mine and completely solves my issue. +1

Comment: @Compo I guess it's due to the fact that the hasn't earned 15 rep yet, his upvote doesn't show up.

Comment: @JDack., meanwhile you've got 15 reputation... ;-) Anyway, [accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) an answer even works with 1 reputation...

Comment: @Compo I stand corrected, and thanks for the up vote, or is it vote up? 

Comment: I did upvote it. I just didn't have 15 at the time where I wrote that. Anyways, accepted it now. ;)

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by LotPings, using the PowerShell command, I was able to come up with this (the only drawback is I have to run the cmd with the /v tag to get delayed expansion to work:

```
SET /p var="Enter Hash: " & FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %F IN (`powershell -NoP -C "(Get-FileHash -Alg sha512 file.zip).Hash"`) DO (if /I %F EQU !var! (echo Match) else (echo No match))
```

To start the command prompt with delayed expansion, type "cmd /v:on" or "cmd /v" in the Windows library directory or in the run box.

Comment: While I drunk a Lot of Pints some decades ago in a nice London pub, my user name is LotPings now ;-)